# Getting the newest record from a database Multiple queries

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a mysql database with vehicles records. I need a fast query that will return the newest records of those records that were updated within the last 4 minutes. For example vehicle "A" may be updated several times a minute so it will appear many times within the last 4min. Same with vehicle B C etc. I need only the most recent entries for each vehicle within a 4 min window. I have tried like this

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable AS a
WHERE a.ts = 
    (SELECT MAX(ts)
     FROM yourtable AS b
     WHERE b.ts > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
       AND b.name = a.name)
```

but it takes too long to produce results >10seconds.

Comment: I'm confused - if a record is updated, why would the table contain multiple records, rather than just the one record?  Also, it would be useful to see the CREATE TABLE definition of your table, and some example data, to help answer the question.

Comment: Actually the table is not updated but new records are inserted to it as if it was a vehicles position log

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
select distinct a.id from yourtable AS a
where a.ts > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE;
```

It gives all vehicles that were updated in last 4/5 minutes.

Thanks,
Rakesh